# AdBlock Edge extention is turn off on each restart

Tags: browser-addons, microsoft-edge, adblock

#### Question :

At every restart, AdBlock addon is desactivated. Requiring me to manually enable the addon.

Is there a way to automaticaly reactivate it with a script or to solve the issue?

#### Version :

Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0
Adblock 1.0.1.0

#### Bug history and reproductibility:

For all I can remember it started 1 years ago. The problem comes and go with no relation to the atch or Windows version. It maybe fix by installing again the addon. but sometimes it doens't help.

Once an user report the issue, we have a reproductibility of 100% for few days. snapshoot of the machine could show the same behavior but not always.

It doens't look related to AdBlock version.